# Объект Set добавляет одинаковые объекты

Tags: javascript

Как правильно работать с объектами при использовании Set?

Ниже пример кода от которого ожидалось, что дублирования не будет:

```js
    let ret = new Set();
    let a = {name:'', value:''};
    let b = {name:'', value:''};
    
    a.name = 'a';
    a.value = 123;
    
    ret.add(a);
    
    b.name = 'a';
    b.value = 123;
        
    ret.add(b);

    console.log(ret);
```

От этого кода, что будет два объекта в Сете:

```
<script>
    let ret = new Set();
    let a = {name:'', value:0};
    
    a.name = 'a';
    a.value = 123;
    
    ret.add(a);
    
    a.name = 'b';
    a.value = 123;
        
    ret.add(a);

    console.log(ret);
</script>
```

Comment: https://learn.javascript.ru/object-copy#sravnenie-po-ssylke

Comment: @AlexeyTen "Как правильно работать с объектами при использовании Set?"

Answer (score 1):

Сделать так как вы хотите не выйдет. Потому что не бывает два или более одинаковых объекта. Если у одного человека две руки и у другого две руки это не значит что это одинаковые люди, это разные личности, то есть разные объекты.
Если Вы сделаете вот так:

```js
const mySet = new Set();

mySet.add({'a': 1, 'b': 2});
mySet.add({'a': 1, 'b': 2});

for (let item of mySet){
    console.log(item);
}
```

В Set будет два объекта потому что они похожи но не одинаковы. Можно сравнивать только значения объектов, а не сами объекты.

```
<script>
    let ret = new Set();
    let a = {name:'', value:0};

    a.name = 'a';
    a.value = 123;

    ret.add(a);

    a.name = 'b';
    a.value = 123;
    // Здесь в Set объект не добавлялся
    // так как он там уже есть, а в Set
    // хранятся только уникальные данные
    ret.add(a);

    console.log(ret);
</script>
```

Отработало все вот так:

```js
let ret = new Set();
let a = {name:'', value:0};
    
a.name = 'a';
a.value = 123;
    
ret.add(a);
    
a.name = 'b';
a.value = 123;

for (let item of ret){
    console.log(item);
}
```